# How do I split a repeating string at a specified position beyond a specific character?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string that I want to split into repeating substrings (new rows actually) based on a repeating pattern. Here is a quick example of the original data string:

```
LS31202010 FG STERLING MR 3X5X10 $3.99 LS31202020 FG STERLING ML 3X5X11 $4.99
```

My initial goal is to be able to split to new rows (substrings) based on the repeating pattern of part numbers ("LS...").

I have tried:

```
text = "LS31202010 FG STERLING MR 3X5X10 $3.99 LS31202020 FG STERLING ML 3X5X11 $4.99"

print(text.split('LS'))
```

I'm getting `['', '31202010 FG STERLING MR 3X5X10 $3.99 ', '31202020 FG STERLING ML 3X5X11 $4.99']` which is close, but not the expected result.

I need to get `['LS31202010 FG STERLING MR 3X5X10 $3.99 ', 'LS31202020 FG STERLING ML 3X5X11 $4.99']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is add back the `"LS"` string to each of your lines.

You can do this by using list comprehension:

```py
text = "LS31202010 FG STERLING MR 3X5X10 $3.99 LS31202020 FG STERLING ML 3X5X11 $4.99"

lines = ["LS" + l for l in text.split('LS') if l != ""]

print(lines)
```

This code adds "LS" as a prefix to all non empty lines it has found.

You can also use the .strip() method to remove leading and trailing spaces if you need to.

Comment: Awesome @Corentin Pane. I added .rstrip() with: ```lines = [l.rstrip(' ') for l in lines]``` to get the exact final result I needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "LS31202010 FG STERLING MR 3X5X10 $3.99 LS31202020 FG STERLING ML 3X5X11 $4.99"

lines = ["LS"+x for x in s.split("LS") if x]
```

Comment: Is the answer _really_ self-describing that you don't have to add few words for illustrations :)?